# XGBoost Library (xgboost.dll) could not be loaded

Tags: python, data-science, xgboost

I can´t import xgboost in pyhton. I instaled by prompt and git clone but aways I have the same error:

Can anyone help me?

`import xgboost`

````
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      2 import subprocess
      3 subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'hello.py', 'htmlfilename.htm'])
----> 4 import xgboost

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xgboost\__init__.py in 
      9 import warnings
     10 
---> 11 from .core import DMatrix, DeviceQuantileDMatrix, Booster
     12 from .training import train, cv
     13 from . import rabit  # noqa

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in 
    173 
    174 # load the XGBoost library globally
--> 175 _LIB = _load_lib()
    176 
    177 

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py in _load_lib()
    156     if not lib_success:
    157         libname = os.path.basename(lib_paths[0])
--> 158         raise XGBoostError(
    159             'XGBoost Library ({}) could not be loaded.\n'.format(libname) +
    160             'Likely causes:\n' +

XGBoostError: XGBoost Library (xgboost.dll) could not be loaded.
Likely causes:
  * OpenMP runtime is not installed (vcomp140.dll or libgomp-1.dll for Windows, libomp.dylib for Mac OSX, libgomp.so for Linux and other UNIX-like OSes). Mac OSX users: Run `brew install libomp` to install OpenMP runtime.
  * You are running 32-bit Python on a 64-bit OS
Error message(s): ['[WinError 193] %1 não é um aplicativo Win32 válido']```
````

Comment: I already save the dll files into win32 and tried to install using cmd

Comment: Found a solution in the meanwhile?